# ngHtml2Js remove multiple module run definitions from result

Tags: node.js, gulp, ng-html2js

I have the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
    // Compile templates
    return gulp.src(templateFiles)
        .pipe(htmlmin({
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            conservativeCollapse: true,
            removeScriptTypeAttributes: true
        }))
        .pipe(ngHtml2Js({
            moduleName: 'my.tpls',
            prefix: 'tpl/'
        }))
        .pipe(concat(libName + '.tpls.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDirectory));
});
```

Which produces several blocks of code in a file, similar to these:

```
(function(module) {
try {
  module = angular.module('my.tpls');
} catch (e) {
  module = angular.module('my.tpls', []);
}
module.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('tpl/my/templates/template1.html',
    '<some-html></<some-html>');
}]);
})();

(function(module) {
try {
  module = angular.module('my.tpls');
} catch (e) {
  module = angular.module('my.tpls', []);
}
module.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('tpl/my/templates/template2.html',
    '<some-html></<some-html>');
}]);
})();
```

This seems very inefficient and sets up a lot of unwanted extra bytes to download.

Is there a way to tweak the gulp task in order to make the result be more like:

```
(function(module) {
try {
  module = angular.module('my.tpls');
} catch (e) {
  module = angular.module('my.tpls', []);
}
module.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('tpl/my/templates/template1.html',
    '<some-html></<some-html>');
  $templateCache.put('tpl/my/templates/template2.html',
    '<some-html></<some-html>');
}]);
})();
```

To clarify; what I'm looking for is the equivalent of the [grunt-html2js singleModule option](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js#singlemodule), but for Gulp. I've allready tried adding `singleModule: true` in my gulp task options for ngHtml2Js. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by overriding the standard ngHtml2Js template, and use gulp-tap to modify the file afterwards. Works like a charm! :-)

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
    // Compile templates
    return gulp.src(templateFiles)
        .pipe(htmlmin({
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            conservativeCollapse: true,
            removeScriptTypeAttributes: true
        }))
        .pipe(ngHtml2Js({
            template: "    $templateCache.put('<%= template.url %>',\n        '<%= template.prettyEscapedContent %>');",
            prefix: 'tpl/'
        }))
        .pipe(concat(libName + '.tpls.js'))
        .pipe(tap(function(file, t) {
            file.contents = Buffer.concat([
                new Buffer("(function(module) {\n" +
                "try {\n" +
                "  module = angular.module('my.tpls');\n" +
                "} catch (e) {\n" +
                "  module = angular.module('my.tpls', []);\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "module.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {\n"),
                file.contents,
                new Buffer("\n}]);\n" +
                "})();\n")
            ]);
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destDirectory));
});
```